# Dynamic case statement using SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following case statement as shown below:

Example:

I have the `case statement`:

```
case cola 
    when cola between '2001-01-01' and '2001-01-05' then 'G1'
    when cola between '2001-01-10' and '2001-01-15' then 'G2'
    when cola between '2001-01-20' and '2001-01-25' then 'G3'
    when cola between '2001-02-01' and '2001-02-05' then 'G4'
    when cola between '2001-02-10' and '2001-02-15' then 'G5'
    else '' 
end
```

**Note**: Now I want to create dynamic case statement because of the values dates and name passing as a parameter and it may change.

```
Declare @dates varchar(max) = '2001-01-01to2001-01-05,2001-01-10to2001-01-15,
                               2001-01-20to2001-01-25,2001-02-01to2001-02-05,
                               2001-02-10to2001-02-15'

Declare @names varchar(max) = 'G1,G2,G3,G4,G5'
```

The values in the variables may change as per the requirements, it will be dynamic. So the case statement should be dynamic without using loop.

**My bad try**:

```
DECLARE @Name varchar(max)
DECLARE @Dates varchar(max)
DECLARE @SQL varchar(max)
DECLARE @SQL1 varchar(max)

SET @Name = 'G1,G2,G3,G4,G5'
SET @dates = '2001-01-01to2001-01-05,2001-01-10to2001-01-15,
              2001-01-20to2001-01-25,2001-02-01to2001-02-05,
              2001-02-10to2001-02-15'

SELECT @SQL =  STUFF((SELECT  ' ' + Value FROM 
(
SELECT 'WHEN Cola Between '''' AND '''' THEN ''' + A.Value + '''' AS Value 
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Value  
        FROM  
        (
        SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(@Name, ',',
            '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Value 
        ) AS A 
        CROSS APPLY Value.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
 ) AS A
) AS B
FOR XML PATH (''), type).value('.', 'Varchar(max)'),1,1,'') + ''

SET @SQL1 = 'CASE Cola '+@SQL+' ELSE '''' END'

PRINT(@SQL1);
```

**Stuck**: But got stuck to split the `@dates` `2001-01-01to2001-01-05` 
into `BETWEEN '2001-01-01' AND '2001-01-05'`.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Seems like you are over-complicating a simple problem here.

Comment: Just create a lookup table with the names, start dates, and end dates.  Then you just have to join it to your queries.  If they reset every year, make the columns `year`, `name`, `start_date`, and `end_date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a temp table (which can be inserted into dynamically) and use it in a `LEFT JOIN`. A `LEFT JOIN` (along with the `COALESCE`) accounts for the `ELSE ''` condition, but if there was no `ELSE` condition and all ranges were represented in the data, an `INNER JOIN` should be used (and no need for the `COALESCE`).

In order to dynamically populate the temp table from two separate variables that whose data is aligned only by position within the CSV list, and one of which is a two-dimensional array needing to be split on both comma and the string "to", I used a CTE (to make it easier to split the two-dimension @Dates variable) and a SQLCLR-based string splitter. The splitter I used is from the [SQL#](http://www.SQLsharp.com/) library (which I am the creator of but this function is in the Free version) but you can use any splitter you like (but please don't use a WHILE loop-based splitter as that is just silly).

```sql
CREATE TABLE #Cola
(
  StartDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
  EndDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
  Name NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

DECLARE @Dates VARCHAR(MAX) = '2001-01-01to2001-01-05,2001-01-10to2001-01-15,
                               2001-01-20to2001-01-25,2001-02-01to2001-02-05,
                               2001-02-10to2001-02-15';

DECLARE @Names VARCHAR(MAX) = 'G1,G2,G3,G4,G5';

-- dynamic population of temp table from two variables (@Dates being 2 dimensional)
;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT vals.SplitNum,
         vals.SplitVal,
         CHARINDEX(N'to', vals.SplitVal) AS [WhereToSplit]
  FROM   SQL#.String_Split4k(@dates, ',', 1) vals
)
INSERT INTO #Cola (StartDate, EndDate, Name)
  SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING(cte.SplitVal, (cte.WhereToSplit - 10), 10)),
         CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING(cte.SplitVal, (cte.WhereToSplit + 2), 10)),
         names.SplitVal
  FROM cte
  INNER JOIN SQL#.String_Split4k(@names, ',', 1) names
          ON names.SplitNum = cte.SplitNum; -- keep the values aligned by position


SELECT tab.fields, COALESCE(cola.[Name], '') AS [Cola]
FROM   SchemaName.TableName tab
LEFT JOIN #Cola cola
        ON tab.cola BETWEEN cola.StartDate AND cola.EndDate
```

Comment: But I am getting `@dates` and `@name` as a comma separated string from front end like as shown above. So how can I insert those into temp table?

Comment: Error: Invalid object name 'SQL#.String_Split4k'.

Comment: @MAK Please see the note about the string splitter. SQL Server does not come with a built-in one.

Comment: @MAK I see in your original attempt you are doing an inline XML-based splitter. At the very least you should make that into an Inline TVF in which case it could be used in place of 'SQL#.String_Split4k' with no other changes. But it also wouldn't hurt to just go ahead and get a SQLCLR-based splitter as they are the fastest _and_ do not have encoding issues like the XML-based method does if you use a special XML character like: `<`, `"`, or `&`.

Comment: I did installation of built-in as you told in a note. But still getting same error. I followed all steps given in :http://www.sqlsharp.com/

Comment: @MAK Is the current database the same as the one SQL# is installed into? If not, you need to fully qualify the name of the function as: `[dbname].SQL#.String_Split4K()`.

Comment: Yes! I got it. Thank you very much for being with me for such long time.

Comment: Can I get the same support of the functions in PostgreSQL 9.3 for doing the same?

Comment: @MAK If you are asking if SQL# runs in PostgreSQL, the answer is no. However, you can write your own string split function in [PL/pgSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql.html).

Comment: Hey I got stuck for the same thing in PostgreSQL. Can you please help me for this?

Comment: @MAK That is a separate question. I cannot fully help with it anyway, but you should open a new question and add a comment with that URL here. I can say that I just found a built-in split function in PostgreSQL: [regexp_split_to_table](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP).

Comment: I have posted new question with more details. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28018991/split-given-string-and-prepare-case-statement